# Storing graph with EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to save a graph into a database as described [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=631772) with EF Code First.

I defined property with collection of adjacent nodes:

```
public class Node {
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

but EF generated only one table for this model:

```
dbo.Nodes
    NodeId (PK, int, not null)
    NodeName (nvarchar(max), null)
    Node_NodeId (FK, int, null)
```

How to force EF to generate many-to-many relationship?

Are there any other ways to store graphs in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class model expresses that a `Node` has one collection of nodes, which can be fully accommodated by the generated table. If you want many-to-many, you'll have to tell EF about your plans.

One thing you can do is make parent and child collections:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Node> ParentNodes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Node> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

EF will create a join table as follows:

```
[dbo].[NodeNodes]
    [Node_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Node_Id1] [int] NOT NULL
```

If you want more meaningful names of the columns you could do this:

```
class NodeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
            .HasMany(n => n.ParentNodes)
            .WithMany(n => n.ChildNodes)
            .Map(c => c.MapLeftKey("ChildNodeId")
                .MapRightKey("ParentNodeId"));
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
var root = new Node { NodeName = "Root" };
root.ParentNodes = new List<Node> { new Node { NodeName = "Par1" }, new Node { NodeName = "Par2" } };
root.ChildNodes = new List<Node> { new Node { NodeName = "Ch1" }, new Node { NodeName = "Ch2" } };
con.Nodes.Add(root);
con.SaveChanges();
```

(Where `con` is a `NodeContext` instance) and see if you like the result.