# Map parent child relationship in EntityFramework on top of existing database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

i need to map some parent children relationship on top of a legacy database, the problem is how the tables are structured.

tableA
  id
  name

tableB
  id
  tableA_parentId
  tableA_childId

As showed I have two foreign key from tableA to tableB

Is there a way to map this relationship with EF i'm using the code first  approach and have a configuration class per table

Comment: that's a bit unusual for the structure (usually you need just one, e.g. just parent and 'many children' follows, is just the other side of it) - what kind of relations do you have between parent and child? is it one-to-many - or from what you said it seems one-to-one ?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9656302/861716)

Comment: Yes I never seen nothing like this and for the data stored on that table is a one-to-many relationship. I gave up to try map this relationship. I will find all child ids on tableB and then i will find all lines on the tableA =/